# Should contain failing in cypress when the match string has a forward slash

Tags: cypress, chai

I was using the `cy.get('selector').should('contain','searchString')` to validate the contents of an error message but the assertion keeps failing. The string I am searching for is this : `Name cannot accept special characters like < > | / : * ? " #; % $ @ ! + ^`

I broke that down into two pieces and figured out that the failure was happening at the `/`. So I tried escaping it with a double and a quadruple slash but it did not work.

Can someone please help me identify the correct way to implement this. Any help will be much appreciated. Cheers!

SAMPLE COMMAND:
`cy.get('[data-test=abc]>p') .should('contain','Name cannot accept special characters like < > | / : * ? " #; % $ @ ! + ^')`

Comment: Are you trying to match the entire string or a part of the string?

Comment: I am trying to match the entire string like so: cy.get('[data-test=abc]>p').should('contain','Site Name cannot accept special characters like < > | / : * ? " #; % $ @ ! + ^')

Comment: Did you copy the string from UI? Looks like there is no space between `#` and `;` in your assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.should('contain')` should work fine. Are you sure you are using the right locator ? I just ran it locally for the string `Name cannot accept special characters like < > | / : * ? " #; % $ @ ! + ^`

My Code:

```
 cy.get('selector').should('contain', 
        'Name cannot accept special characters like < > | / : * ? " #; % $ @ ! + ^')
```

Test Runner SCreenshot:

[image: test runner with forward slash]

In case your selector is correct and you're still getting the error. You should check if you have a backslash `\` in your message or not. To escape backslash you have to write backslash 3 times more. So `\ = \\\\`. So In your string if we replace the forward slash with backslash it would be like this:

```
cy.get('body > :nth-child(3)').should('contain', 
        'Name cannot accept special characters like < > | \\\\ : * ? " #; % $ @ ! + ^')
```

[image: test runner with backslash]

Comment: I just figured out the issue. The CSS was adding an extra space in the UI before the forward slash and that's why it was failing. Thats why when I split the string it worked as I was trimming the spaces.In the UI`Name cannot accept special characters like < > |  / : * ? " #; % $ @ ! + ^`In the HTML`Name cannot accept special characters like < > | / : * ? " #; % $ @ ! + ^`

Comment: Thanks so much for nudging me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out :)